# one to many relationship with many columns

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, one-to-many

I am VERY new to SQL and do not know that much about it, but I am a quick learner. I have a database with Item IDs and Quantities on Hand (qoh) along with some other columns that I am not having issues with. The problem is that when I tell it to give me the item id column with the qoh column, it gives me almost 500 rows for each individual item because the qoh is different so I literally have about 12 million rows. Now, what I am looking for is the most recent quantity for each item. I am assuming that this is a one-to-many relationship and since I am below a noobie to SQL, I don't even really know where to begin. This is what I have so far:

```
SELECT DISTINCT item_id, qty_on_hand
FROM database.inv_mast, database.inv_loc
ORDER BY item_id ASC
```

Oh and I'm using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio

Here is what I want:

```
| item_id |qty_on_hand|
|123456789|   93      |
|456789123|   87      |
|789456123|   74      |
```

etc.

But what I'm getting is:

```
| item_id |qty_on_hand|
|123456789|   85      |
|123456789|   82      |
|123456789|   92      |
```

etc.

I am getting the same item_id at least 4000 times because the database is telling me what the qoh was for literally every second of time since we've had the item. I only want what is in the warehouse at the time of me running the query. I apologize for all the noobness, but I literally don't know SQL.

Comment: Add the `create table` statements of the 2 tables in the question.

Answer (score 3):

You are doing a cross join by just using ",". What you need to do is a inner join I think.

```
SELECT DISTINCT im.item_id, qty_on_hand
FROM database.inv_mast im
INNER JOIN database.inv_loc in on im.item_id = in.item_id
ORDER BY item_id ASC
```

You also should look at left and right joins.

So in summary using "," is like using a cross join

You really need to learn joins to understand these queries, check out the site below.

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

Comment: if item_id is in both tables, you'll need to identify which one to use in the select and order by too.  And, probably a group by item_id, so that a SUM(qty_on_hand) can be extracted as well.

Comment: I like your answer but not the link to w3fools. That site is full of errors.

Comment: luckily item_id is in only one of the tables. I think I am just having a hard time explaining this correctly. I tried what @Thomas wrote and it doesn't like the word 'in'. I have been able to get a column that lists the last date modified, but it also gives every single time to the second. So now, I have 4000 rows per item letting me know the quantity at every increment of time since we've had the item! So frustrating! This database I am using is really huge and I've been thrown to the wolves in search of an inventory list using SQL with absolutely no training.

Comment: The word 'in' is just an alias for your table change it to whatever you like. Perhaps inv would make more sense.

Comment: Add your tables and columns to the question and I will try to help.

Answer (score 1):

The *from* clause `FROM database.inv_mast, database.inv_loc` creates the cartesian product. Narrow that down using a `WHERE` condition.